# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to university.pojo.Schedule

Tags: swing, hibernate, netbeans, classcastexception, pojo

There are some similar questions, but none of them could help me.
I tried to fill a JTable with data from a DB using hybernate and everething was ok when I extracted information from a single table, but when I tried to do the same with joined tables I started getting an exception.
This are some of my pojo and mapping files(they are generated by NetBeans)

```
public class Schedule  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer scheduleId;
     private Days days;
     private Groups groups;
     private Lessons lessons;
     private Rooms rooms;
     private Teachers teachers;
     //constructors, getters and setters
   }

public class Groups  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer groupId;
     private String groupName;
     private Set schedules = new HashSet(0);
     //constructors, getters and setters
   }

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 03.10.2015 17:16:15 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="university.pojo.Schedule" table="schedule" catalog="university" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="scheduleId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="schedule_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="days" class="university.pojo.Days" fetch="select">
            <column name="day_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="groups" class="university.pojo.Groups" fetch="select">
            <column name="group_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="lessons" class="university.pojo.Lessons" fetch="select">
            <column name="lesson_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="rooms" class="university.pojo.Rooms" fetch="select">
            <column name="room_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="teachers" class="university.pojo.Teachers" fetch="select">
            <column name="teacher_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 03.10.2015 17:16:15 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="university.pojo.Groups" table="groups" catalog="university" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="groupId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="group_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="groupName" type="string">
            <column name="group_name" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="schedules" table="schedule" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="group_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="university.pojo.Schedule" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is the main part

```
package university.ui;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import university.pojo.Schedule;
import university.pojo.Teachers;
import university.util.HibernateUtil;

public class uni extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public uni() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private static String QUERY_FOR_TEACHER="from Teachers t where t.teacherName like '";
    private static String QUERY_FOR_TEACHER_SCHEDULE="from Schedule sd "
            + "join sd.lessons sdl "
            + "join sd.rooms sdr "
            + "join sd.groups sdg "
            + "join sd.teachers sdt "
            + "join sd.days sdd "
            + "where sdd.dayName like '";

    private void runQueryForTeacherSchedule(){
        executeHQLQuery(QUERY_FOR_TEACHER_SCHEDULE + "mondey" + "' "
                + "and sdt.teacherName like '" + "bruce" + "'",2);
    }

    private void runQueryBasedOnTeacherName() {
        executeHQLQuery(QUERY_FOR_TEACHER + enterTeacherName.getText() + "%'",1);
    }
    private void executeHQLQuery(String hql, int sc) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
            List resultList = q.list();
            switch(sc){
                //displayResult(resultList,sc);
                case 1: displayResult1(resultList);
                    break;
                case 2: displayResult2(resultList);
                    break;
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            he.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void displayResult1(List resultList) {
        Vector<String> tableHeaders = new Vector<String>();
        Vector tableData = new Vector();
        tableHeaders.add("Names"); 
        for(Object o : resultList) {
            Teachers teachers = (Teachers)o;
            Vector<Object> oneRow = new Vector<>();
            oneRow.add(teachers.getTeacherName());
            tableData.add(oneRow);
        }
        teacherNameTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders));
    }

    private void displayResult2(List resultList) {
        Vector<String> tableHeaders = new Vector<String>();
        Vector tableData = new Vector();
        //tableHeaders.add("Room");
        tableHeaders.add("Group");
        //tableHeaders.add("Start");
        //tableHeaders.add("End");
        for(Object o : resultList) {
            Schedule schedule = (Schedule)o;
            Vector<Object> oneRow = new Vector<>();
            //oneRow.add(schedule.getRooms().getRoomNumber());
            oneRow.add(schedule.getGroups().getGroupName());                        
            //oneRow.add(schedule.getLessons().getLessonStart());                        
            //oneRow.add(schedule.getLessons().getLessonEnd());
            tableData.add(oneRow);
        }
        teacherScheduleTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders));                    
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane2 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        enterTeacherName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        teacherNameTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        teacherWorkDay = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        teacherScheduleTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        enterTeacherName.addCaretListener(new javax.swing.event.CaretListener() {
            public void caretUpdate(javax.swing.event.CaretEvent evt) {
                enterTeacherNameCaretUpdate(evt);
            }
        });

        teacherNameTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null},
                {null},
                {null},
                {null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Names"
            }
        ));
        /*
        teacherNameTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    final JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                    final int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                    final int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
                    // Cast to ur Object type
                    String urObjctInCell = (String)target.getValueAt(row, column);

                }

            }

        });
        */
        teacherNameTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                teacherNameTableMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(teacherNameTable);

        teacherWorkDay.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "mondey", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday" }));

        teacherScheduleTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Room", "Group", "Start", "End"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane4.setViewportView(teacherScheduleTable);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(enterTeacherName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(teacherWorkDay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 429, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(enterTeacherName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(teacherWorkDay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 379, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jTabbedPane2.addTab("Teachers", jPanel4);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null},
                {null},
                {null},
                {null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null},
                {null},
                {null},
                {null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
        jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
        jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 345, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
        );

        jTabbedPane2.addTab("tab2", jPanel5);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel6Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel6);
        jPanel6.setLayout(jPanel6Layout);
        jPanel6Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 555, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel6Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 427, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane2.addTab("tab3", jPanel6);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane2)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane2)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void enterTeacherNameCaretUpdate(javax.swing.event.CaretEvent evt) {                                             
        runQueryBasedOnTeacherName();

    }                                            

    private void teacherNameTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //int row=teacherNameTable.getSelectedRow();
        //String tableClick=(teacherNameTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        runQueryForTeacherSchedule();
    }                                             
/**/
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(uni.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(uni.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(uni.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(uni.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new uni().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField enterTeacherName;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
    private javax.swing.JTable teacherNameTable;
    private javax.swing.JTable teacherScheduleTable;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox teacherWorkDay;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I used this tutuorial as a guidline for writing my program, changing it were necessary.
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html

This is the exact exception message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to university.pojo.Schedule
    at university.ui.uni.displayResult2(uni.java:74)
    at university.ui.uni.executeHQLQuery(uni.java:44)
    at university.ui.uni.runQueryForTeacherSchedule(uni.java:28)
    at university.ui.uni.teacherNameTableMouseClicked(uni.java:275)
    at university.ui.uni.access$100(uni.java:13)
    at university.ui.uni$2.mouseClicked(uni.java:142)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception occurs for calling   at `university.ui.uni.runQueryForTeacherSchedule(uni.java:28)`

because this runs a query Having joins, and then that query returns `List<Objects[]>` thats why it is throwing exception

```
ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to university.pojo.Schedule
```

where   `Ljava.lang.Object` is object array.
if you want shedule for teacher then

change query to

```
private static String QUERY_FOR_TEACHER_SCHEDULE="select sd from Schedule sd "
        + "join sd.lessons sdl "
        + "join sd.rooms sdr "
        + "join sd.groups sdg "
        + "join sd.teachers sdt "
        + "join sd.days sdd "
        + "where sdd.dayName like '";
```

now this will return Schedule Object.